# Разные DataGridView, одинаковые имена колонок

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть 2 разных dataGridView, можно ли что бы они содержали одинаковые имена колонок?

dg1.Columns[1].Name = "OrderId"
dg2.Columns[1].Name = "OrderId"

Если да, то как это сделать? А то VS2017 ругается

Comment: Вы имена колонок динамически хотите менять?

Comment: Просто на форме два грида, через коллекцию колонок хочу выставить имена

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас в гриде вообще ничего нет и он пустой, тогда добавить в каждый из них по столбцу Вы можете так:

```
dg1.Columns.Add("OrderId", "OrderId");
dg2.Columns.Add("OrderId", "OrderId");
```

Если же у Вас уже есть хотя бы 1 столбец в гриде и Вы хотите изменить ему имя, например, при загрузке приложения, то:

```
dg1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "OrderId";
dg2.Columns[0].HeaderText = "OrderId";
```